# VideoView (Can't create handler inside thread)

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm trying to make my VideoView to work with Asynctask. However, there are some errors I couldnt understand. Could anyone please check on my codes? I'm getting this error "`java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`"

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
                MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(
                        MainActivity.this);
                mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

                Uri video = Uri.parse(videoPath);
                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                videoView.requestFocus();
                videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        videoView.start();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("Video Play Error :" + e.toString());
                // finish();
            }
            return null;

        }
```

Comment: why u are using AsyncTask for preparing videoView?

Comment: yes, this is my doinbackground task

Comment: i mean why u are using AsyncTask?

Comment: My video is downloaded from a remote server, I want the video to stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update view on `doInBackground` method. move the code for updating the view on `onPostExecute` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Could you show me which part of codes to be moved?

Comment: can you post your stack trace from log cat?

Comment: I tried moving everything from doinbackground to onpostexecute and it worked. Do I actually need an Asynctask for Video Streaming?

Comment: AFAIK it will not work in background as you need to update it in video view also. so i think it is useless to do in "doInBackground"